# vertical alignment and floats

Tags: html, css

I'm sorry if my question seems stupid, but I spent too much time on this. I have a div display block containing two span, one on the right and the other one on the left.

```
<div class="user-bar">
    <span class="username">Martin GOYOT</span>
    <span class="user-options"><input type="button" class="disconnect" value="déconnexion"/></span>
</div>
```

I tried two thing to get them vertical aligned: First one, getting these two floats, but the problem is that I can clearly see that they are out of flow (normal) and thereby, if I apply a background, to the container, it doesn't cover them:

http://jsfiddle.net/M7Ffd/1/

Second solution, let the first in the flow and put the second one as a float, but the result is that I can't find out how to vertically aligning them:

http://jsfiddle.net/M7Ffd/2/    (be careful of the button, it is not really vertically aligned even if it looks like)

So, the question is: what is the best solution, and, how to fix at least one of these two misbehaviour.

thanks, and sorry, I'm a css newbie.

Answer (score 1):

Vertical alignment is a hard issue. And floating seems to be everyone's first goto solution for everything. Avoid the gotos, how about using

```
position: absolute;
right: 0;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M7Ffd/3/

Comment: +1. Just FYI, Martin GOYOT, the floating never obeys `vertical-align`. Falmarri's suggestion of using absolute positioning works nicely. For the button, you could use `right:0px` to keep it aligned to the right.

Comment: I like your solution as it is quite simple. But, take a look at the button, it doesn't look like vertical aligned… Is there another rule to add?

Comment: It looks vertical aligned to me. The span should be vertical aligned (I assume you mean vertically centered). If it's not, it's probably your browser applying various styles to the input element.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/M7Ffd/4/)

```
.user-bar {
padding: 0.5em;
margin: 0 1em 1em 1em;
background-color: green;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 1.25em;
height:30px;
min-width:300px;
}
.user-options {
display: inline-block;
background-color: #CCC;
float: right;
}
.username {
float: left;
background: yellowgreen;
}
```

​
Setting the minimum width and giving height solves the alignment + Background solution.

Comment: Using min-width and height also is a VERY slippery slope to go down if you're trying to have your site be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Use the clearfix hack on the parent element of the 2 floated children to resolve your issue.

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: "\0020"; display: block; height: 0; overflow: hidden; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { zoom: 1; }
```

I updated your fiddle to show you it http://jsfiddle.net/M7Ffd/5/

Comment: you're answer is very interesting, thanks. I will probably not use it, because the "two floats" solution doesn't satisfy me, but I'll keep it in mind for future issues with floats. Thank you for sharing.